# Is there any possible health risks to eating subway every day?

Tags: nutrition, side-effects, food-safety, refined-foods

Every day, I eat an average 6' subway sandwich, which is around 300 calories plus a drink (sweet tea).  There may be a possibility that the meats are processed and i can realize that, but is eating subway everyday really good for you?